# How do I remove Windows 7 installation from partition?

Tags: windows-7

I want to remove Windows 7 installation from a partition **WITHOUT** destroying any other data on it **using Windows 7** booted from another partition.

The most obvious way would be to just delete the Windows directory, but I don't have permission to do that. When I open the security settings and try to change them, I'm told that access is denied and I can't move on from there. I'm using administrator account.

So what do I do?

UPDATE: In the meantime, I found [this](https://superuser.com/q/69840/36601) question asking the same thing, but the answer there doesn't help.

Comment: reset the permissions using http://superuser.com/questions/60700/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-delete-files-on-windows-7, you should be able to delete the files. I use [this piece of batch file](https://gist.github.com/972013) since it recursively goes into all directories

Comment: @Sathya♦ Seems to be working so far.

Comment: @Sathya♦ Well, I did takeown /f D:\windows /r and it did some work and now when it has finished, when I tried to set permissions, I got the access denied once again.

Comment: Try running the scripts again. If it fails, it will list the folders for which changes could not be applied - for these you can try changing the owner manually via the Properties -> Security tab

Comment: @Sathya♦ The script lists all directories there are in the windows directory, but when I right click on them, I get my username and administrators group shown with full permissions.

Comment: @Sathya♦ Turns out that I can now delete each file and directory in the windows directory, but not the windows directory itself. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: ah good to hear that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The most obvious way would be to just delete the windows directory, but I don't have permission to do that. When I open the security settings and try to change them, I'm told that  access is denied and I can't move on from there. I'm using administrator account.

The [SIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) on the existing Windows directory won't be valid, so you'll have to reset the SIDs to the one present on your new Windows install.

You can do this by right clicking on the Windows folder, heading over to Properties & deleting  the existing SID and then adding your current user account. To complete this, you will also need to change the owner of the files(via the advanced option). But in my experience, this has never worked well on individual folders & it doesn't apply them recursively to all sub-directories.

Using the command prompt, you can use the [below two commands](https://gist.github.com/972013) to take ownership of the folders & then reset the SIDs.

```
takeown /r /d y /f *
icacls * /reset /t /c /q
```

Note that this doesn't preserve or respect existing security settings, to run this *only* if you want to reset it.