# Need Administrator Permission to Delete a Folder

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove Windows 7 installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/338114/how-do-i-remove-windows-7-installation)

I'm trying to delete a folder (in windows 7), but I get this message:

> "You need permission to perform this action"
>
> "You require permission from Administrators to make changes to this
>   folder"

I find this strange as I am the only user on this OS, and I am also set as the Administrator.

Can anyone help?

Comment: try C:\ users :- to see if there is another user called 'admin' or 'user with admin'

Comment: question title (of the above mentioned closed dupe) is different but the steps required to remove the folder is the same